# Need help with ER diagram

Tags: databases

I am making database on Disaster Management. There are four tables.

1. `DisasterEvent (eventid, name, glideID, status, description, date_occurred,  date_ended, disaster_type)`
2. `People(eventid, num_deaths, num_injuries, num_affected)`
3. `Homes (eventid, num_homes_destroyed, num_homes_damaged, total_insured_loss, total_uninsured_loss)`
4. `Place (place_id, city, state, country, postal_code)`

In my design, I have *one to one relationship* between **`People`** and **`DisasterEvent`** , and *one to one relationship* between **`Home`** and **`DisasterEvent`** because for a particular disaster there is only one **`People`** table that we are concerned and same for **`Home`** table. 
Now, **`Place`** has *many to many relationship* with **`DisasterEvent`** because at particular place there can be many disasters over time and same disaster could occur many place at once.

What am I trying to achieve is able to map number of affected people by the particular disaster event at certain place. For this I think there needs to be three way relationship among **`DisasterEvent`**, **`Place`** and **`People`**. How do I achieve this?

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have a 1-1 relationship between **DisasterEvent** and **People** now, you can **not** distinguish any relation between **People** and **Place**. If several **Places** are related to a single **DisasterEvent**, all those places are related to the same instance of **People**.

If you want to map the **People** affected by the **Event** at a **Place**, you should relate **People** to **Place** instead of to **DisasterEvent**.

As long as an event always occurs at at least one place, you can always relate your **People** to your **DisasterEvent** via the **Place** where it occurred.

On a sidenote, I would use *Location* instead of *Place*, and maybe the more precise *Victims* for *People*, as well as maybe *Damage* for *Home*.

Comment: Thank you. I see the problem now. What kind of relation do you think people will have with place. Is it going to be one to many or one to one?

Comment: I think you'd have one set of victims (people) at each location (place), so a one-to-one. Since you have a many-to-many relation between event and place, the relation with people would technically be one to one between people and (disasterevent-place).